# Upload File in windows application to web server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to upload multiple image file to the web server using my windows application. Here is my code

```
     public void UploadMyFile(string URL, string localFilePath)
    {
      HttpWebRequest req=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);                     
      req.Method = "PUT";
      req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

      // Retrieve request stream and wrap in StreamWriter
      Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
      StreamWriter wrtr = new StreamWriter(reqStream);

      // Open the local file
      StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(localFilePath);

      // loop through the local file reading each line 
      //  and writing to the request stream buffer
      string inLine = rdr.ReadLine();
      while (inLine != null)
      {
        wrtr.WriteLine(inLine);
        inLine = rdr.ReadLine();
      }

      rdr.Close();
      wrtr.Close();

      req.GetResponse();
    }
```

I referred the following link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446517.aspx

I am getting exception
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method not allowed.

Comment: what kind of application running at web server end?

Comment: This is ASP.Net MVC Application running on server I want to upload files without interrupting the web application

Comment: Did you ever manage to upload a *single* file to the server? What makes you think the problem is the client and not the server?

Comment: I am trying single file only. but this exception "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method not allowed." is killing me everytime

Answer (score 1):

Why are you reading and writing in terms of lines when these are image files? You should be reading and writing in blocks of bytes.

```
public void UploadMyFile(string URL, string localFilePath)
{
      HttpWebRequest req=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);

      req.Method = "PUT";
      req.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

      using (Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream()) {

          using (Stream inStream = new FileStream(localFilePath,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.Read)) {
              inStream.CopyTo(reqStream,4096);
          }

          reqStream.Flush();
      }

      HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebReponse)req.GetResponse();
}
```

You could also try the much simpler `WebClient` way:

```
public void UploadMyFile(string url, string localFilePath)
{
    using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
        client.UploadFile(url,localFilePath);
    }
}
```